# How to parse function calls in loop?

Tags: python, translate

i am writing a simple language to describe sequences of function calls.

*I am using a python, but only algorithm answers also be accepted.*

For example i have a code:

```
for 2:
{
  a
  for 3:
  {
    b
    c
  }
}
```

How can i proceed it to a such sequence? ( for n: {block} where n is times block appeared )

a
b
c
b
c
b
c
a
b
c
b
c
b
c

I know that there is exists lexers and tokens, but how can i do it much simpler? Because language hasn't any more constructions and needed only for describing such sequences. Tokens will be very diffucult for me now ( but if you post a code i will be very happy :) )

Thanks

Comment: There's no reason to expect that an ad-hoc solution with less powerful tools would be *simpler* than using the high-level tools designed for your task.

Comment: But i need to integrate it in my python project, that works with such sequences. How can i do? What i need to use? What tools are talking about?))))

Comment: Get [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) or some other parser generator and write yourself a parser.

Comment: you are using both `:` python blocks and `{}` blocks? my gosh why?

Comment: Thanks, i now this tool. How can i parse "embedded" loops ( sorry, i can't translate from my language this term ) with pyparse? I cant imagine

Comment: Tadhd McDonald-Jensen, i found it to easier parse a number if i use a separator such as :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that I do not have any experience with parsing and very limited experience with regex.  This was more a challenge for myself more than a solution but regardless it may be useful to you.

Your syntax isn't that far off from a python generator, a valid python generator that produces the values you want would look like this:

```
def temp():
    for _ in range(2):
      yield 'a'
      for _ in range(3):
        yield 'b'
        yield 'c'
```

So there are only two substitutions you would have to make, the `for n` into `for _ in range(n)`:

```
def sub_for(match):
    return "_ in range({})".format(match.group(0))

def my_code_to_generator(code):
    # match a number that is preceded by "for " and right before a ":"
    code = re.sub("(?<=for )\d+(?=:)",sub_for,code)    
    ...
```

And changing arbitrary letters `a` into yield statements `yield 'a'`:

```
def sub_letter(match):
    return "yield {!r}".format(match.group(0))

def my_code_to_generator(code):
    code = re.sub("(?<=for )\d+(?=:)",sub_for,code)
    #match a single character that has whitespace around it.
    code = re.sub("(?<=\s)[A-Za-z](?=\s)", sub_letter, code)
    ....
```

Then putting it in a `def` statement and executing it as python code would produce an iterator that generates the characters you desire:

```
import re

def sub_for(match):
    return "_ in range({})".format(match.group(0))

def sub_letter(match):
    return "yield {!r}".format(match.group(0))

def my_code_to_generator(code):
    code = re.sub("(?<=for )\d+(?=:)",sub_for,code)
    code = re.sub("(?<=\s)[A-Za-z](?=\s)", sub_letter, code)
    code = "def temp():\n    " + code.replace("\n","\n    ")
    namespace  = {}
    exec(code,namespace)
    return namespace["temp"]()

text = """
for 2:
{
  a
  for 3:
  {
    b
    c
  }
}""".replace("{","").replace("}","") #no curly braces in python!
```

---

```
>>> list(my_code_to_generator(text))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c']
>>> "".join(my_code_to_generator(text))
'abcbcbcabcbcbc'
```

Yes I realize that this is a very impractical and clunky solution, I don't expect this to be a final answer but until someone posts a better one it may let you get some results. :)

Comment: LoL! Thanks, it opened my eyes. I just changed syntax  to python code and yield statements. It became very easy. Code that i gave in a question was from a generator, so i need to change only few lines of code to generate python code as you gave. Thanks))))))

Comment: Wow, I was not expecting this answer to be accepted. Well always glad to help!

Comment: It was a genius. As project completes i would send you a results, there are an interesting project. ( Generator of music based on rythm algorithm generator, that generates code, compiles it into assembly of virtual machine, that finally translates it into wave frames )

Comment: Hi again, unfortunately on a big data your code gives "memory error", on a huge data "SystemError"(((